# PHP populate single array with no keys

Tags: php

I have an indexed array like this:
    $indexed = array(0=>2,1=>7,3=>9)

But i need a single array, without indexes, like this: 
    $notIndexed = array(2,7,9)

Zend_Form does not accept $indexed as parameter for the function populate() for multi checkboxes but works fine with $notIndexed

How can i dynamically transform $indexed to $notIndexed

Thanx for answers

Comment: you didn't even bother to search for it on php.net.

Comment: @Twisted1919: out of curiosity - how would you search for it (assuming you know as much as OP does)? What search query would you try?

Comment: Just typed in google something like `php get array without index` and the page is full of results solving my problem. I see where you are going with this, but really, even without knowing exactly what he wants, the search results from google would have help him.

Comment: Like i said to zerkms: "thanks for your answer, it's right, and i'm a dumb who need to sleep :) before to post here i tried the good function array_values()... but not on the good array... so it didn't worked :'( sorry for disturbing ^^ "

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$notIndexed = array_values($indexed);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it's right, and i'm a dumb who need to sleep :) before to post here i tried the good function array_values()... but not on the good array... so it didn't worked :'( sorry for disturbing ^^

Answer (score 1):

Are you serious? Use, `array_values($indexed)`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Comment: true, but the answer would have been found with little effort.

Comment: Sorry,
The mistake was somewhere else so array_values was not working... 

CAN BE DELETED WITH MY EXCUSES....

Answer (score 0):

`$notindex = array_values($indexed)`